# Symfony2 initialize error

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem with my Symfony2 project. On the localhost it works fine, but on the server I got that error:

> "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag::initialize()
>   must be of the type array, string given, called in
>   /home/visset/ftp/cms/dashboard/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 252
>   and defined"

I checked it and to `initialize()` function passed empty string.

What is the reason of that problem?

Comment: What data are passed in localhost?

Comment: array(1) { ["_security_default"]=> string(453) "C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":365:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:7:"default";i:2;s:322:"a:4:{i:0;C:31:"visset\loginBundle\Entity\admin":111:{a:4:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:6:"visset";i:2;s:60:"$2a$08$jHZj/wJfcVKlIwr5AvR78euJxYK7Ku5kURNhNx.7.CSIJ3Pq6LEPC";i:3;b:1;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:1:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Rolerole";s:9:"ROLE_USER";}}i:3;a:0:{}}";}}" }

Comment: Can you improve your question by writing what is on line 252 and maybe a little bit of context?

Comment: Did you find a solution?